# Which IP is logged when sending request with PHP/cURL?

Tags: curl, ip

Client (**IP_#1**) via browser accessing web page PHP/cURL(**IP_#2**) and doing request/response to (**IP_#3**). Response received at **IP_#1** i.e. clients browser.

What is logged at (**IP_#3**)?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how it is done but I’d say **IP_#2**.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I understand 1 accesses 3 via 2. -> edit

Comment: and how it should be done to have IP_#1 logged only ?

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible if IP_#3 is independent third party. The requesting machine is is always logged so IP_#1 would have to request to 3 themself.